# Last row indices of cells using unique function in matlab

Tags: matlab

To all who can shed light on my situation:
Right now I am battling the function, unique with cells. After I import data from a .csv, I store it in a struct that is an Nx1 cell, see below.

```
manuf = {'Tim'; 'Tim'; 'John'; 'John'; 'John'; 'bill'; 'bill'; 'bill'; 'bill'}

manuf = 

    'Tim'
    'Tim'
    'John'
    'John'
    'John'
    'bill'
    'bill'
    'bill'
    'bill'
```

To find the indices of the FIRST time each row is repeated, I can use the following command:

```
[name,first_ndx] = unique(manuf)

name = 

    'John'
    'Tim'
    'bill'


first_ndx =

     3
     1
     6
```

However, I am very interested in the indices of the last row each string is repeated. The output would look something like this.

```
last_ndx =

     5
     2
     9
```

This could be easily done with the command, `[~,last_ndx] = unique(manuf,'rows','last')` if the cells were doubles, however, this is not the case as `unique` can not perform the `rows` option with cells. It should be noted that the number of rows in `manuf` is variable depending on the .csv file. Any ideas as to how to find indices of last row of unique values?

Comment: From the documentation it looks like `unique(manuf,'legacy')` should still work for your case Do not have MATLAB around so cannot test :(

Comment: If you have a 1D cell array, the `rows` flag isn't required....

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a little bit of hacking, the last index of each name group = length(manuf) + 1 - the first index of each name group in the reverse of manuf. So you can simply do:

```
>> [~,last_ind_rev]=unique(manuf(end:-1:1))

last_ind_rev =

     5
     8
     1

>> last_ind = length(manuf) + 1 -last_ind_rev

last_ind =

     5
     2
     9
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `unique` in older versions of MATLAB used to report the **last** occurrence of each unique entry that is to be stored in the second output of `unique` which is what you're after. It was only in recent versions of MATLAB where they started to report the first occurrence as is seen in your results.

You can specify this by using the `legacy` option with `unique`:

```
>> [~, last_idx] = unique(manuf, 'legacy')

last_idx =

     5
     2
     9
```

Comment: Or `[~, last_idx] = unique(manuf, 'last')`, which is easier to read